# Using JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

I am trying to integrate **Vimeo API** in android, and I'm getting the following error:

> Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

#### Here's my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Video video = VideoPlayActivity.video;

        TestApp d = new TestApp();
        d.onCreate();
        mApiClient = d.getmApiClient();

        String uri = video.getVideoUri().toString();
        mApiClient.getInstance().fetchNetworkContent(uri, new ModelCallback<Video>(Video.class) {
            @Override
            public void success(Video video) {
                Log.i(TAG, "get success.");
                // use the video
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(VimeoError error) {
                Log.i(TAG, error.getErrorMessage());
                // voice the error
            }
        });
}
```

And these are the important methods in TestApp:

```
public class TestApp extends Application {
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");

        sContext = this;

        Configuration.Builder configBuilder = getClientIdAndClientSecretBuilder();
        VimeoClient.initialize(configBuilder.build());
        mApiClient = VimeoClient.getInstance();
    }
    
    public Configuration.Builder getClientIdAndClientSecretBuilder() {
        String clientId = "dc62dc72e8c7cf4d0b7bb025d41e2a7649ddc0a4";
        String clientSecret = "SRbzt7mLfbA0l5aEV8lXINE54nRGkSp8S2i+wOp9paOqQsEKkwC5MtdwFPHiVqX7DTCooPVWAxPVjG8/pjjPbl+7LNTXTuSDit1oZGtCjkBYFqahb95J4pAHzEumdNhs";
        return new Configuration.Builder(clientId, clientSecret, SCOPE);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question?